# delete row if column value is in list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete several rows from my Dataframe, based on values in another list.
This would be an example how it works:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [101,202,303,101,457,35,6]})
drop =[101,202]
df3=df3[(df3.Number != 101)&(df3.Number != 202)]
df3.head()
```

Since for my real Dataframe the list of values to drop is large, i was wondering if it is possible to do it with an iteration

I tried to call

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [101,202,303,101,457,35,6]})
drop =[101,202]
df3=df3[df3.Number != [i for i in drop]]
df3.head()
```

bu this give me the following error

> Lengths must match to compare

Comment: You're looking for `isin`: `df3[~df3.Number.isin(drop)]`

Comment: (The `~` is used to say `not`)